# Передать результат JS в контроллер

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Всем привет.
Пользователь вносит сумму, из предложенных на экране монет. 1.2.5.10.
При нажатии на 1 внесённая сумма увеличивается1. При нажатии на 2 внесённая сумма увеличивается на 2 и тд
Если сумма превышает стоимость пользователь получает сдачу.
Пользователь вносит сумму, покупает выбранный напиток.
Как Мне передать сумму которую пользователь внес.
Что сделал Я:
View

```
<h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
<p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
@foreach (var entity in Model)
{
     var idButton+=1;
     var buttonIncrease = increase + idButton;
    <button id="buttonIncrease" name="increase" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">@entity.Cost</button>
}

@*test*@
<h2>внесенная сумма</h2>
<input type="text" name="field" value="0" />
@*test*@
```

Model:

```
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        private decimal _cost;
        private int _quantity;

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        public decimal Cost
        {
            get=>_cost;
            set
            {
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    _cost = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Количество денег не может быть меньше 0");
                }
            }
        }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Purchase(int result, IFormCollection colletion)
{
    string ss = ViewBag.SumMoney;
    return Ok(result);
}
```

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.increase'), function(v) {
  v.addEventListener('click', inc);
});

function inc() {
  var div = this.parentElement;
  var input = div.children.item(1);
  input.setAttribute('value', (parseInt(input.getAttribute('value')) + 5).toString());
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="decrease" type="button">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="field" value="0" />
  <button class="increase" type="button">+</button>
</div>

тут уже не работает
<input type="text" name="field" value="0" />
тут уже не работает
```

Написал такой код, он вроде работает. Значение на вью меняются. Вот только за приделом див он не работает. А Мне нужно одно поле и 4 кнопки там будет меняться  сумма. Как это код Js повесить на кнопки

Comment: Позже смогу ответить, но сразу скажу ViewBag передает из Контроллера в Представление, то что не поместилось в Модель,  а Вам нужно наоборот из Представления, получить что то в Контроллер.

Comment: Я буду очень признателен за помощь. Я перепробовал все что мог, ViewBag Моё последнее пристанище. Его лучше вообще не использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для передачи чего-либо из форм на странице, в представлении в первой строке кода, всегда указывается модель с которой будет работать это представление.
2. В представлении нужно явно указать, что это форма для ввода данных, добавляяя строку `form method="post"`

```html
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" asp-controller="Название контроллера" asp-action="PaymentPost">
    <div>
      // какой то код
      <input asp-for="Payment" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Передать что-либо" />
  </form>
</div>
```

3. В вашей модели, можно добавить такое свойство, в котором будет храниться сумма, которую ползователь заплатил. `public int Payment { get; set; }`
4. В контроллере, кроме метода типа Get, нужно создать такой метод типа Post, назвать который можно PaymentPost. Что то типа

   `public IActionResult PaymentPost(int Payment) {/* логика обработки, полученного результата Payment */ return RedirectToAction("Index");}`

В итоге, вам нужно разобраться с ASP.NET Core, прежде чем его пытаться использовать. Вот здесь [видео](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9NehG1_SkN5ahKL6Q_ozPR), в котором коротко говорится о том как работает ASP.NET Core, а вот здесь репозиторий с кодом для [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky) на .NET 5,